# Redefinitions of Lagrangians using EOM

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, effective-field-theory

I am trying to understand an statement of [this](http://arxiv.org/abs/1412.7151) paper. In section 2 this Lagrangian is introduced

$$\mathcal{L}_4=-|D_{\mu}\phi|^2-\lambda_{\phi}|\phi|^4-\frac{1}{4g^2}F_{\mu\nu}^2\qquad{}\mathcal{L}_6=\frac{1}{\Lambda^2}[c_r\mathcal{O}_r+c_6\mathcal{O}_6+c_{FF}\mathcal{O}_{FF}],$$
where $\Lambda$ is an energy scale suppresing the dimension 6 operators and
$$\mathcal{O}_r=|\phi|^2|D_{\mu}\phi|^2\qquad{}\mathcal{O}_6=|\phi|^6\qquad{}\mathcal{O}_{FF}=|\phi|^2F_{\mu\nu}F^{\mu\nu}.$$

On the second paragraph of section two it i said

> Integrating by parts and uing the EOM, we can elimiate $\mathcal{O}_r$ in favor of $\mathcal{O}'_r=(\phi{}D_{\mu}\phi^*)^2+h.c$

Now, I would like someone made this computation explicit. It puzzles me what role the equation of motion of $\phi$ play in all this (since it must be a mess involving the gauge field). Also, is it legitimate to use equations of motion to make redefinitions in Lagrangians?

Comment: have you started the calculation? e.g. what is the EOM for $\phi$? can you add it to the question?

Answer (score 6):

This is a particular example of a general theorem in effective field theory: if you have an operator that is proportional to the lowest order equations of motion, you can push that operator to higher order in perturbation theory by a field redefinition. This is especially useful if you are working to a fixed order in perturbation theory, in which case you might be able to eliminate that operator from your calculation completely (by pushing it to a higher order in perturbation theory than you are considering). In this example, after integration by parts you find a dimension six operator proportional to the lowest order equations of motion. The general theorem tells you that you can do a field redefinition to replace the dimension six operator with operators of higher dimension.

Let's start by re-writing your operator by integrating by parts
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{O}_r = |\phi|^2 |D \phi|^2 =- \frac{1}{4} (\phi D_\mu \phi^*)^2 - \frac{1}{4} |\phi|^2 \phi (D_\mu D^\mu \phi^*) + h.c.
\end{equation}
Where equality here really means up to total derivatives. Now the lowest order equation of motion is $D_\mu D^\mu \phi = 0$. We should not use this equation of motion directly in the lagrangian. However, we can take advantage of this fact to do a field redefinition to push the operator proportional to $D_\mu D^\mu \phi$ to higher order, let's see how that works.

The only terms in the Lagrangian we need to keep are the kinetic term and the operator proportional to the lowest order equations of motion (the technical name for this is a `redundant operator'). 
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{L} \supset \phi (D_\mu D^\mu \phi^*) - \left( \frac{1}{4\Lambda^2} |\phi|^2 \phi (D_\mu D^\mu \phi^*) + h.c.\right)
\end{equation}
Now the field redefinition we need to do is
\begin{equation}
\phi \rightarrow \phi + \frac{1}{4\Lambda^2} |\phi|^2 \phi
\end{equation}
(and similarly for $\phi^*$). You can check that this field redefinition pushes the redundant operator to higher order. Even though the redundant operator looks like it is a dimension 6 operator, this field redefinition pushes it to higher order. We can always remove redundant operators in this way, for a proof of the theorem in general see for example the review of EFT by Cliff Burgess, hep-th/0701053, especially around equation 21.

Comment: I know this i probably very easy but, could you please be more explicit on how integrating by parts gives the first equation you write?

Comment: and what do you exactly mean with lowest order equation of motion? lowest order in what?

Comment: No problem! Split up O_r= 1/2(O_r+h.c.). Then take the first term and split in half again but without h.c.: O_r=1/2(O_r + O_r). Take the first term of that split and integrate by parts. You should find what I wrote above, plus a piece that cancels the second term in the split. Then do the same procedure on the h.c. piece. As for your other question, I mean lowest order in phi. Burgess explains that theorem well if you want more details.

Comment: excuse me but, what i integrating $O_r$ by parts?

Comment: $O_r = \phi^* \phi D \phi D \phi^* = - D(\phi^* \phi D \phi) \phi^*$ (where I have dropped a total derivative, which gives a vanishing contribution to the action using gauss's law + the fact that the fields die off asymptotically at infinity)

Comment: first remark, shouldnt you also take the complex conjugate of the covariant derivative when writing $O_r$  which changes things a bit?

Comment: second remark, iw it legitimate uing Gauss' theorem having covariant derivatives, instead of normal derivatives? if so, why?

Comment: (1) No, the covariant derivative doesn't get complex conjugated. If $D \phi= (\partial + i e A)\phi$, then $D\phi^* = (\partial - ie A)\phi^*$, the complex conjugation is built into the definition of $D$. (2) Yes it is valid. The lagrangian is charge neutral, so if I have something like $X D Y$, then the charges of $X$ and $Y$ satisfy $e_X = - e_Y$. So write $X D Y = X \partial Y + i e_Y X A Y$. Then this is (using ordinary integration by parts with $\partial$ plus the fact $e_X=-e_Y$) $XDY = - (\partial X) Y - i e_X X A Y = -((\partial + i e_X A)X) Y = - (DX) Y$.

Comment: (1) but this is cheating, I mean, you are complex conjugating $(\partial+ieA)$ when taking $-i$ for the $\phi^*$ case. What do you mean with the complex conjugation i built in the definition of $D$? I thought that $D=(\partial+ieA)$ was the definition

Comment: No no no, the form of the covariant derivative always depends on the thing that it is acting on. This is true in the simple U(1) case but also much more generally in Yang Mills and in GR. In this case the point is that the charge $e$ in the formula $\partial + i eA$ really means the charge of whatever the covariant derivative acts on. So if $\psi$ has charge $a$ and $\phi$ has charge $b$, then $D \psi = (\partial + i a A)\psi$ and $D \phi = (\partial + i b A)\phi$.

Comment: (2) great answer. You are being very helpful!

Comment: (1) ok I learned some things here, thanks!

Comment: No problem! Glad I could help!

Comment: Why don't you take into account the $\phi^4$ interaction when getting the EOM?

Comment: This is really about field redefinitions you can do to simplify a calculation, the fact that the EOM is involved is incidental. If you were really interested in the EOM you would need to include the phi^4 term. But that's not the point, the point is that you can get rid of a redundant interaction with a field redefinition, and it just turns out that the lowest order eom is what guarantees you can do the field redefinition. The fact that this field redefinition is so useful is more or less an artifact of doing perturbation theory.

Comment: my point is, how do you define "lowest order eom"? I mean, $\phi^4$ is in the lowest order Lagrangian $\mathcal{L}_4$, why do you exclude it?

Comment: The bottom line is that you should do whatever field redefinition is useful to simplify your life. The lowest order eom in this case means the gauge invariant generalization of the free eoms for phi. This is useful because we could cancel the redundant operator. The eom was linear in phi, that was one of the key things that let us push the eom to higher order. If you want, you can write an interaction proportional to the full nonlinear eom for phi and try to cancel it with a field redefinition, if you can then you should! But I suspect you can't usefully do that...

Comment: ...because nonlinearities mix orders of perturbation theory so o don't think you could push the whole thing to higher order, you'd just shuffle things around at the order you were working with. I strongly recommend going through the proof in Burgess I linked to in the answer if you haven't already.

Comment: So to reiterate, by "lowest order eom" in this case I mean lowest order in phi.

Comment: a question relating to this. In chiral perturbation theory you expand the Lagrangian in powers of momenta over the hadronic scale. So the Lagrangian is orderder in a fashion $\mathcal{L}_4+\mathcal{L}_6+\ldots$. Now imagine we expand the Lagrangian in terms of the pions. Every term $\mathcal{L}_i$ spits out a series in $1/f$. Imagine I have a redundant operator (I stress that this operator is written using the pions, not $U$) In all this field redefinition business, do I have to use $f$ or the original $p/\Lambda$ power counting to push it to next order? or I can use both